# Yii Criteria Condition Order By in Query Syntax

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I have the code below and i am trying to add `'order' => 'creation_date DESC'` or something similar but i cant get the right sintax (i am trying to order the results in DESC order);

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $total = EmployerContract::model()->count();

        $pages = new CPagination($total);
        $pages->pageSize = 10;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

        $posts = EmployerContract::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: $criteria->order = 'creation_date DESC';

Comment: @Kevin thanx that works fine was trying to change the findall() but your approach seems better and it works